# Tychonoff cube is the continuous image of the Cantor cube

Tags: general-topology

I'm reading a paper that states that the Tychonoff cube $[0,1]^A$ is the continuous image of the Cantor cube $D^A$, where $D$ is the two point set consisting of $0,1$ and $A$ is some uncountable set. Does anyone know a reference or proof for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that $[0,1]$ is a continuous image of $D^{\mathbb{N}}$ by the map $f(s)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{s(n)}{2^{n+1}}$. (If you identify $D^{\mathbb{N}}$ with the usual Cantor set, this is just the Cantor function.)  So, $[0,1]^A$ is a continuous image of $(D^{\mathbb{N}})^A\cong D^{\mathbb{N}\times A}$.  If $A$ is infinite, then $A$ is in bijection with $\mathbb{N}\times A$, so $[0,1]^A$ is a continuous image of $D^A$.